# removing bad data from a data file using pig

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-pig

I have a data file like this

```
1943 49 1
1975 91 L
1903 56 3
1909 52 3
1953 96 3
1912 82 
1976 66 3
1913 35 
1990 45 1
1927 92 A
1912  2
1924 22 
1971  2
1959 94 E
```

now using pig script I want to remove the bad data like removing those rows which have characters and empty fields
I tried this way

```
records = load '/user/a106524609/test.txt' using PigStorage(' ') as 
(year:chararray, temperature:int, quality:int); 
rec1 = filter records by temperature != 'null' and (quality != 'null ')
```

Comment: Please show your code so far and errors you are having

Comment: records = load '/user/a106524609/test.txt' using PigStorage(' ') as 
(year:chararray, temperature:int, quality:int);
rec1 = filter records by temperature  != ' ' and (quality != ' ');

Comment: At a high level, this isn't really possible to know if `1912  2` for example is a (year and temperature) record, or a (year and quality) record

Comment: And personally, I would find Spark more easier to filter this data in than Pig

Comment: suppose this is like the first column is the year and the second column is temperature and third one quality @cricket_007

Comment: Just curious: How was the data created? If you want to prevent bad data, then you should ideally fix it there

Comment: @cricket_007 this is a big file including more than 1000 rows .. i just need to remove bad data from quality column i.e quality should only contain [0123456789]

Comment: if data in quality doesn't match 0123456789 then remove that row

Answer (score 1):

Load it as lines

```
A = load 'data.txt' using PigStorage('\n') as (line:chararray);
```

Split on all whitespaces

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(line, '\\s+')) as (year:int,temp:int,quality:chararray);
```

Filter by valid strings

```
C = FILTER B BY quality IN ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');
```

(Optionally) Cast to an int

```
D = FOREACH C GENERATE year,temp,(int)quality;
```

---

In Spark, I would start with a regex match of the expected format.

```
val cleanRows = sc.textFile("data.txt")
    .filter(line => line.matches("(?:\\d+\\s+){2}\\d+"))
```